# Uniquely identifying a user from a POST request with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, post, express

I'm making a browser game that utilizes voice communication, to record audio in the browser I'm using [wami-recorder](https://code.google.com/p/wami-recorder/) which uses flash to send a POST request to the server with the recorded audio, only it doesn't seem to give me any control over the request.

My game server, which is written in node.js/express, needs to be able to identify the client from the audio it's received, as well as pair it with the correct web socket from socket.io

I've considered using the ip address, however it wouldn't work if there were multiple clients with the same address. I've also considered assigning a unique URL to the client (one of the only things wami let's me do) for them to send the audio to, except I wouldn't want that url stolen somehow and for someone else to have the ability to send audio to it

So I'm wondering if there's a way a post request in express.js can consistently identify a client.

Comment: Your usual options are to include a piece of data in each post request that identifies the user or to have the user "login" and set a cookie that identifies the user and the cookie should be sent automatically with the post request so you can then examine the cookie server-side to see which user is sending.

Comment: I don't have any control over the post request though, so I can't send a piece of data.

Comment: Then, you can set a cookie before the post and the system will automatically include the cookie with the post request.

Comment: I got it to work! thanks a bunch, you want to put that in an answer  so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your usual options are:

1. To include a piece of data in each post request that identifies the user
2. To have the user "login" and set a cookie that identifies the user and the cookie should be sent automatically with the post request so you can then examine the cookie server-side to see which user is sending.

If, as you say in your comments, you can't influence the data that is sent with the request, then you would want to set a cookie that identifies the user before the request is sent and the browser will automatically include the cookie with the request and then your server-side code can examine the cookie that comes with the request to see which user it is.  This is the usual way that one "logs in" to a web-site and the server then keeps track of which user a given request is from.