# node js server propplem

Tags: node.js, express, sockets, server

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
var i = new Number;
i=0;
app.get("/", function(req, res){
    i++
    console.log(i);
});
app.listen(8080);
```

I created a very small node js project. I have a problem. when I create a variable like above, it doesn't evaluate for each user separately. that is, when a user requests a get, I want it to be 1 each time. 
Sample
 my problem is that when a jack user enters a site, if he doesn't log out, someone who enters the site's home page from another device enters his account with jack.
how can I do that?

Comment: Are you looking to increment the i at individual user level not at every time the get method is being called ?

Comment: @ASP yes ı want

Comment: I hope this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32426146/uniquely-identifying-a-user-from-a-post-request-with-node-js) will help you.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer for your question is to simply declare and increment the variable inside the function passed to `app.get`, but I'm going to assume that you would like a situation where, for a given user's series of requests, the number will increment.

The simplest way to do this is using a server side session, which is provided by the [express-session](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session) library. Additionally, in order for this to work, you need to call `res.end()` in order to send the cookie associated with the server session back to the user's browser. More information on sessions generally can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3804209/what-are-sessions-how-do-they-work).

Below is code to replicate the intent of what you have there, but incrementing for each request from a unique browser instance (identified by the same cookie value associated with the server session):

```
const express = require('express');
const session = require('express-session');

const app = express();

app.use(session({
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  secret: 'secret',
  cookie: {
    maxAge: 60000
  }
}));

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  if (!req.session.value) {
    req.session.value = 0;
  }

  req.session.value++;
  console.log(req.session.value);
  res.end();
});

app.listen(8080);
```

Comment: my problem is that when a jack user enters a site, if he doesn't log out, someone who enters the site's home page from another device enters his account with jack.

Comment: @YusufCıbıl in general, it sounds like you are leaking the state outside of the request (eg, having the `i` variable outside of the request handlers). Using the session as I've shown covers this a bit, as it fetches the session associated with the browser and pulls the value from there, instead of manipulating the global variable.